# Updating a GUI element when datasource changes

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight app and a listbox in it whic I populate using:

```
listItems.ItemsSource = App.AvailableProductList;
```

If i then add an element to the AvailableProductList, the listbox will NOT be automatically updated.
Does anyone knows how to update the listbox?

tks,
Oscar

Comment: What is the type of 'AvailableProductList'? Is it an ObservableCollection<T> or a BindingList<T>?

Comment: It is a List<Products>, and Products is a custom type with a String name and a int quantity.
What do do not happen is the refresh of the list. I would like to have a Repaint(), DataBind() or a method like this so I can force the rebind so the listbox "notices" there is an item added or an item removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the List, I changed to ObservableCollection and it worked :)

Tks!